# C# MS Charts configuration [ Histogram ]

Tags: c#, histogram, bar-chart

I would like to display Histogram by using built in MS Chart.
My data are divided on 14 classes where width of each one is:

```
double ClassWidth = (data.Max() - data.Min()) / ClassNR;
```

I'm setting AxisX range:

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = h_begin;  // 0.3
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = h_end;    // 0.5
```

And then in the Loop i'm adding data. Plus i'm setting something like this:

```
chart1.Series["" + (i + 1)]["PixelPointWidth"] = ""+ClassWidth;
chart1.Series["" + (i + 1)]["DrawSideBySide"] = "True";
```

Result:
[Results than i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwoar.png)

and i would like to get something like that:
[Result that i;m looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTf8g.png)

Comment: Try to make `ClassWidth` an int and also don't let it depend on the data but on the number of datapoints or in your case the numer of series! Also: Why so many series? One series with colored points should be enough, no?

Comment: Ye i changed it to just one series + i used only `chart1.Series["Hist"].SetCustomProperty("PointWidth", "1");` now its working great :)